# Between in SPServices with multiple date fields

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

I have the following CAMLQuery.

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <Or>
    <Or>
      <Or>
        <Or>
          <Or>
             <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Titulo</Value>
             </Eq>
             <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />
                <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDTribMobil</Value>
             </Geq>
             <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />
                <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDTribMobil</Value>
             </Leq>
          </Or>
          <Geq>
             <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
             <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDINSS</Value>
          </Geq>
           <Leq>
             <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
             <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDINSS</Value>
          </Leq>
       </Or>
       <Geq>
          <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />
          <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCRF</Value>
       </Geq>
       <Leq>
          <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />
          <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCRF</Value>
       </Leq>
    </Or>
    <Geq>
       <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />
       <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDTribFederais</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>
       <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />
       <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDTribFederais</Value>
    </Leq>
  </Or>
   <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeSegurodeVida</Value>
   </Geq>
   <Leq>
      <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteSegurodeVida</Value>
  </Leq>
</Or>
 </Where>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   </OrderBy>
 </Query>
```

The code is basically: Consult a list of Sharepoint 2013 that contains multiple columns of dates, and form there are multiple fields of type date. The problem is that between the form I created. The CAMLQuery returns nothing. Just one mistake that CAMLQuery is incorrect.

Anyone know how to make a CAMLQuery with multiple date fields?

tks

Comment: Do you want the "Title = Titulo" inside or outside of all the Date <Or> filters? I can see the issue is the unbalanced CAML, but the answer will vary based on whether you want Title=Titulo AND a series of <Or> filters on your dates - or, if you want Title=Titulo to be one of your <Or> conditions, along with all the Date ones.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you want to evaluate Title=Titulo as an <Or> condition along with all your Date filters, then the below is the CAML you need. If instead you want Title=Titulo to be true AND your series of <Or> filters, comment on or update your question and I'll update the answer.

CAML:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>Titulo</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDTribMobil</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDTribMobil</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDINSS</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDINSS</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
            <Or>
                <Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDINSS</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDINSS</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCRF</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCRF</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
                <Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeCNDTribFederais</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteCNDTribFederais</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                    <Or>
                        <Geq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataDeSegurodeVida</Value>
                        </Geq>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>txtDataAteSegurodeVida</Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Comment: This CAMLQuery "works". It does not return any error (as my returning) but any data that I put on the form, the code is returning all results list

Comment: With such a large variety of <Or> filters, I'm not surprised :) Joking aside, because all the conditions are <Or> based, only one needs to be true within a given item for it to be returned. Have you validated that all items should not be returned? The processing of the CAML is done by the SP Object Model and, as you saw, if the CAML is malformed you instead get an error. Most all the time, if a CAML query is returning data but it's not what you're unexpecting, the issue is the query itself.

Comment: I understand. I will validate all fields and if I can CAMLQuery operating in accordance with what the client asked, we publish here. Anyway, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found for my problem. I know it's not the best code in the world, but it works :)

```
calmQuery = "<Query>"+
                 "<Where>";
//If the Subcontratados is not empty and all the dates are, applies the ""
if(Subcontratados != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil == '' && txtDataAteCNDTribMobil == '' && txtDataDeCNDINSS == '' && txtDataAteCNDINSS == '' && txtDataDeCRF == '' && txtDataAteCRF == '' && txtDataDeCNDTribFederais == '' && txtDataAteCNDTribFederais == '' && txtDataDeSegurodeVida == '' && txtDataAteSegurodeVida == '')){
        calmQuery += "";
//If the Subcontratados is not empty and no other date also applies the AND
}else if(Subcontratados != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
        calmQuery += "<And>";
 //If none of the above conditions applies the OR
 }else{
        calmQuery += "<Or>";
 }
        calmQuery +=   "<Eq>"+
                          "<FieldRef Name='Title' />"+
                          "<Value Type='Text'>"+Subcontratados+"</Value>"+
                       "</Eq>";

        if(txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' ||  txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' ||  txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "<Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' && txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' ||  txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "<Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeCRF != '' && txtDataAteCRF != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "<Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "<Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' && txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "<Or>";
        }


            //If txtDataDeCNDTribMobil and is txtDataAteCNDTribMobil is not empty
            if(txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != ''){
                calmQuery += "<And>"+
                                "<Geq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataDeCNDTribMobil+"</Value>"+
                                "</Geq>"+
                                "<Leq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Certid_x00e3_o_' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataAteCNDTribMobil+"</Value>"+
                                "</Leq>"+
                              "</And>";
            }
            //If txtDataDeCNDINSS and txtDataAteCNDINSS is not empty
            if(txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' && txtDataAteCNDINSS != ''){
                calmQuery +=  "<And>"+
                                "<Geq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataDeCNDINSS+"</Value>"+
                                "</Geq>"+
                                "<Leq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x002f_INSS' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataAteCNDINSS+"</Value>"+
                                "</Leq>"+
                               "</And>";
            }
            //If txtDataDeCRF and txtDataAteCRF is not empty
            if(txtDataDeCRF != '' && txtDataAteCRF != ''){
                calmQuery += "<And>"+
                                "<Geq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataDeCRF+"</Value>"+
                                "</Geq>"+
                                "<Leq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CRF' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataAteCRF+"</Value>"+
                                "</Leq>"+
                             "</And>";
            }
            //If txtDataDeCNDTribFederais and txtDataAteCNDTribFederais is not empty
            if(txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != ''){
                calmQuery +=  "<And>"+ 
                                "<Geq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataDeCNDTribFederais+"</Value>"+
                                "</Geq>"+
                                "<Leq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_CND_x0020_Tribu' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataAteCNDTribFederais+"</Value>"+
                                "</Leq>"+
                              "</And>";
            }
            //If txtDataDeSegurodeVida and txtDataAteSegurodeVida is not empty
            if(txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' && txtDataAteSegurodeVida != ''){
                calmQuery +=  "<And>"+
                                "<Geq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataDeSegurodeVida+"</Value>"+
                                "</Geq>"+
                                "<Leq>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Vencimento_x0020_Seguro_x0020_de' />"+
                                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>"+txtDataAteSegurodeVida+"</Value>"+
                                "</Leq>"+
                              "</And>";
             }
        if(txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "</Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' && txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "</Or>";
        }else if(txtDataDeCRF != '' && txtDataAteCRF != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "</Or>";
         }else if(txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' && txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "</Or>";
         }else if(txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' && txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '' && (txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '')){
            calmQuery +=  "</Or>";
         }

        //CLOSE - If the Subcontratados is not empty and all the dates are, applies the ""
        if(Subcontratados != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil == '' && txtDataAteCNDTribMobil == '' && txtDataDeCNDINSS == '' && txtDataAteCNDINSS == '' && txtDataDeCRF == '' && txtDataAteCRF == '' && txtDataDeCNDTribFederais == '' && txtDataAteCNDTribFederais == '' && txtDataDeSegurodeVida == '' && txtDataAteSegurodeVida == '')){
            calmQuery += "";
        //CLOSE - If the Subcontratados is not empty and no other date also applies the AND
        }else if(Subcontratados != '' && (txtDataDeCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribMobil != '' || txtDataDeCNDINSS != '' || txtDataAteCNDINSS != '' || txtDataDeCRF != '' || txtDataAteCRF != '' || txtDataDeCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataAteCNDTribFederais != '' || txtDataDeSegurodeVida != '' || txtDataAteSegurodeVida != '')){
            calmQuery += "</And>";
        //CLOSE - If none of the above conditions applies the OR
        }else{
            calmQuery += "</Or>";
        }
    calmQuery +=    "</Where>"+
                    "<OrderBy>"+
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title' />"+
                    "</OrderBy>"+
                "</Query>";
```