# One date field with multiple single time fields - how to combine the fields?

Tags: r, date, time

I searched the forum for this query and only found posts on [combining hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944327/combine-date-hits-hour-hits-minute-field), and a query on [multiple date fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127162/between-in-spservices-with-multiple-date-fields).

The data I am dealing with has an overall date field (with no time) which is called:

DateofVisit

Then there are several other time fields only such as:
•   Arrival
•   Assessment
•   Seen
•   Conclusion
•   Departure

Using R I want to also add the date to the time fields using DateofVisit variable. However, it gets tricky because if people arrive at 10pm, for example, then the date will change across the different variables. So it is not as simple as combining the DateofVisit variable to the time variables.

Was wondering if anyone had any pointers on how to best solve this?